# Is there a way to start a service to create new user before the login prompt appears if there are not users using systemd?

Tags: systemd, users, login

I intend to create a new user before the getty login prompt appears (when there is not existing users)
Basically, the adduser command can be triggered from a script that will be started before the getty login service

It may look something like this:

**user_add.service**

- execute a script to check for existing user (getent shadow), if the user doesn't exist prompt to add new user and set password

...

..

..

**getty.service**
- This service should not start before the user_add.service process is complete